# UIButton setAttributedTitle auto layout issue

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I use attributed string for setting title for my button and it won't stretch width of the button based on the text (symbols) length . In case I use normal title `[button setTitle:.....]` it works perfect and width of the button is equal to the text. So I can see all letters.

I used font awesome to grab image from font and set it as attributed string.

```
FAKFontAwesome *userIcon = [FAKFontAwesome userIconWithSize:16];
[userIcon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIFont *font = [PFFont boldFontOfMediumSize];

NSAttributedString *connectString =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Connect", @"")
    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

NSAttributedString *user = [userIcon attributedString];
NSAttributedString *combined = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", user, connectString];

[self.button setAttributedTitle:combined forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in this case button want stretch correctly based on given string.

I set constraints programmatically and I don't have any restriction on width, so the width should resize automatically based on content as I suppose and it works for usual string but not for attributed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your button in the storyboard.
2. Goto Editor
3. Select "Size to Fit Content"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I add a space to the format string trail, fix the issue. You can try it!

```
  NSAttributedString *combined = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ", user, connectString];
  [self.button setAttributedTitle:combined forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```